# AWS CLI Command Line: How to use "--query" to output multiple source lines

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, query

I am using aws-cli version 1.7.8 to get the `--query` output to create one record that is derived from multiple lines.
In this case I am trying to get specific information from `describe-instances`.

In the `describe-instances` command, we get lines / sections that refer to `RESERVATIONS` , `INSTANCES` , and `TAGS` .

I am able to simply run the new AWS CLI command to get the information from all three lines individually:

RESERVATION line:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx --query 'Reservations[*].ReservationId'`

INSTANCE line:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx --query 'Reservations[*].[Instances[*].[InstanceId,ImageId]]'`

TAG line:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`]]'`

I can run these 3 commands, and concatenate the results to form 1 record.

Does anyone know if there is a way I can run this as ONE (1) command, instead of 3 distinct commands?

I've tried PIPE and other forms of syntax, but I'm not able to find a good solution as of yet.

Can I get the equivalent output of these 3 commands from a single command?

Comment: Run the Windows commands from a powershell prompt in Windows. Then it will return results.

Answer (score 42):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id i-77777777 \
  --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,ImageId,Tags[*]]' \
  --output text
```

This command will print Instance Id, AMI ID, Key and Value Tags.
You can see more examples here:
[Controlling Command Output from the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html)

Comment: Adding a brief description of what the command is doing might be helpful.

Comment: would this only work in non-windows based CLI ? I tried it in Windows CMD - it didn't but - in CentOS - it worked.

Comment: Where is some documentation on the query syntax???

Comment: Yes.
Here you are: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/controlling-output.html

Comment: The AWS docs only has a few examples. Isn't there a full spec on the syntax?

Comment: It may be easier to output in JSON and use 'jq' to manipulate. I want to do similar things to purge entries from security groups, but only selected combinations of attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Just to add, if someone wants resulting object, use this syntax in the end of command: `.{id: InstanceId, image: ImageId}` so on so forth.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows (cmd.exe, cmder.exe, etc.), one must use double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') around the query string. Otherwise the console simply prints the path in the query and doesn't even generate an error.

Answer (score 1):

For info, listing all instances names with their instance ID:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filters 'Name=instance-state-name,Values=running' \
  --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].{Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0],InstanceId:InstanceId}' --output table
```